# How do I open a website in a Tkinter window?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to build a simple web browser with Tkinter. I would like to know how I can open a website in Tkinter/Python.

Comment: What specifically is the issue you're having? Loading the page off the web? Rendering the HTML? The question as it is posed is *way* to broad for Stack Overflow (web browsers are ridiculously complex).

Comment: @MalikBrahimi The OP is specifically asking how to open a website in Tkinter not with other tools.

Comment: This is the perfect job for JavaFX, though

Comment: I wan't to create a window with a website that loads in it. Is Java better than python? I'm slowly learning that Java is probably the language of choice when it comes to creating software.

Comment: While tkinter may not support what you are looking for, other popular alternatives such as Qt or wxWidgets do support that.

Answer (score 9):

You cannot easily do what you want. Tkinter has no way to render html. You would have to parse the HTML and CSS and Javascript yourself, and translate the information for display on a canvas or text widget.

If all you want to handle is paragraphs, bold, italic, and headings, it might not be too hard. To render most real-world html with css and javascript would likely take you thousands of hours of work to get right.

At one point there was an effort to create a tkinter html widget, but that project hasn't seen any significant activity in years (http://tkhtml.tcl.tk/), and as far as I know was never integrated with Tkinter. It showed a lot of promise, but it also showed that rendering HTML is a very, very difficult task.

Comment: This is the correct answer, as far as I know, why did you down vote, whoever are you? Maybe a simple working example should also be nice, but...

Comment: @SeanPedersen: I've updated the answer in case you want to change your vote. While I don't really care about the vote per se, I think it's misleading to suggest in the comments that rendering HTML in tkinter is possible. It would take a **tremendous** amount of effort to render modern web pages.

Comment: @BryanOakley Yes, you are absolutely correct. I have removed my rants.

Comment: Thanks Bryan Oakley, you answered my question. I knew something wasn't right about Tkinter...it's very archaic. I should probably stick with Visual Basic, it comes with a web browser tool.

Comment: @BroMichael: I think you'll find that most (all?) GUI toolkits for python lack a full fledged HTML widget, though some can render some very basic HTML. But yes, if you want a robust way to render web pages, you should probably stick with visual basic or some other .NET language.

Answer (score 2):

First, you can parse the HTML content with [HTMLParser](https://docs.python.org/2/library/htmlparser.html). Secondly (and this is a very in-depth process) you can display the data; as it's being parsed, in a canvas containing a bitmap, while detecting user input. That said, Bryan is correct.

Answer (score 1):

one way

```
import tkinter
import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()
frame = tkinterweb.HtmlFrame(root)
frame.load_website('https://pokemondb.net/')    
frame.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
root.mainloop()
```